# Android - errors during initialization of Freemarker library Configuration

Tags: android, freemarker, template-engine

I want to use templates for generating html pages on Android application . Later on I want to print these prepared pages. I thought I could use Freemarker template library. 
But during initialization - in the code :
try
            {
            cfg = new Configuration();

```
            cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(MSprzedazSesja.folderAplikacjiNaKarcie.getAbsolutePath()+MSprzedazSesja.folderWzorcowWydruku));
            cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
            tempFaktura = cfg.getTemplate("wzorzecFaktura.ftl");
        }
```

I get error:  E/AndroidRuntime(7608):   at freemarker.core.Configurable.(Configurable.java:139) 
It gets error at line cfg = new Configuration();
I tried to use that code in windowed Java application and it worked Ok. 
Is it possible to use Freemarker in Android at all??

Answer (score 0):

http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/Exception-when-using-FreeMarker-in-Android-td4654256.html

I met the same problem today. After searched in google, I found this answer:
**'Android is not an officially supported target '**. So I am considering to replace freemarker in my project